# Python dictionary accumulative value to individual values

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

Now I have a Python dictionary my_dict:

| level_1 | level_2 | level_3 | level_4 | level_5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 8 | 11 | 13 |

`my_dict = {'level_1':2, 'level_2':2, 'level_3':8, 'level_4':11, 'level_5':13}`

The value of the dictionary now is accumulative, I am wondering how to get the python dictionary with individual value:

| level_1 | level_2 | level_3 | level_4 | level_5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 | 6 | 3 | 2 |

Thanks in advance for any helps!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592. What do you imagine are the logical steps to solving the problem? Where are you stuck? Note well that this is *not a code-writing service, nor a discussion forum*. We are looking for a *specific question*, not just a description of a task. "Thanks in advance for any help" [does not qualify](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236).

Comment: Also: it isn't clear why the original data is a dictionary in the first place. Key names like `level_1`, `level_2` etc. are not very useful. If you only want to know the "position" of each element, and if you will do the processing by looping over it, then a list makes much more sense.

Comment: there is nothing "accumulative" in the values but they are described as terms of [telescopic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series#In_general) sequence/series

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` for that, especially if your data grows for many columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict, index=[0])
df.diff(axis=1).fillna(df)
```

Without pandas, you may use a simple `dict` comprehension:

```
{k: my_dict.get(f'level_{int(k[-1])}', 0) - \
    my_dict.get(f'level_{int(k[-1]) - 1}', 0) \
    for k in my_dict.keys()}
```

Comment: @Nin17 I had used `v` initially but changed to using only the keys. Ty for the observing :)

Comment: you should use ```for k in my_dict``` rather than ```for k in my_dict.keys()``` as it's faster

Comment: @Nin17 not sure if this matters here? But ty for chiming in ;)